# How to enable variable from form into class Timer

Tags: c#

I have Main form class here:

```
        public partial class Main : Form
        {
            public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               //here I want to call function runtime() from SchedulingTimer class
                 // in oder to run afunc() every second or any Interval
            }
           public void afunc()
                {
                  Message.Show(textbox1.Text);
                 }
       }
```

And I have a Timer Class:

```
public class SchedulingTimer
    {

        public static  void runtime()
        {
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
            myTimer.Interval =10000 ; // 1000 ms is one second
            myTimer.Start();

        }

        public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
                //call function from main which have agrument textbox.Text
                   afunc();//or any function which variable sended from Main form
        }
    }
```

But when I call `afunc` in `DisplayTimeEvent` method it has some error cause this is a `static` method so cannot access `textbox1.Text`. I think my code has some mistake.

**UPDATE:**

- I set `myTimer.Enable= true` ,then, I click on `Button` but nothing
  happend. It seems `afunc()` doesn't work.
- create instance of Main method in DisplayTimeEvent. `Main objMain=new Main();` `objMain.afunc();` and there are some detail in afunc:

  ```
      string keyw = cbkeyw.Text.ToString();
      string link = cblink.Text.ToString();

       if (radiobutton.Checked)
      {
          Yahoo yahoo = new Yahoo();
          yahoo.RunProxyYahoo(proxylist, keyw, link, numPage, CountID);
      }
      else
          MessageBox.Show("Please choose Search Engine!");
  ```

  I call Yahoo Class in my afunc, that so really confused. When I click `Button`, it only show:`("Please choose Search Engine!");` event though I 've checked in `radiobutton` already

Comment: Can you click [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17584267/edit) and update your question with the exact error message you get ?

Comment: You have to create instance of Main method in DisplayTimeEvent. 
Main objMain=new Main();
objMain.afunc();

Comment: @maruti I've updated my question. Please take a look at that again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` not the `System.Timers.Timer`.  The former will avoid cross threading issues when trying to access the main form.

I question why you need the `SchedulingTimer` class.  I would have the code in the form.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Main : Form
{
  Timer myTimer = new Timer { Interval = 10000 };

  public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTick);
     myTimer.Start();
  }
  public void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs ea)
  {
     myTimer.Stop();
     Message.Show(textbox1.Text);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked.!!! But how can I set it call function every second but only in one  specify minute. For example: in Min= 30-> run-> min=31 it stop

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should do this: `_timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it`

```
  Timer myTimer = new Timer();

            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
            myTimer.Interval =10000 ; // 1000 ms is one second
            myTimer.Enabled = true
```

Comment: Thank you, as you recommended, I set Timer.Enabled= true. But then, I click on Button -> no thing happen, afunc doesn't run. Help

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is because the `runtime` method is static so you cant access non-static methods/properties directly.

You could pass an `Action` into the `runtime` method so it will fire the method you pass in from your main `Form`

Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SchedulingTimer.runtime(afunc);
}


public class SchedulingTimer
{
    public static void runtime(Action callback)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        // when timer fires call the action/method passed in
        myTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => callback.Invoke();
        myTimer.Interval = 10000; // 1000 ms is one second
        myTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

But if you are accessing UI controls from the Timer you may have to invoke back to the UI thread

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SchedulingTimer.runtime(() => base.Invoke((Action)delegate 
    {
       afunc();
    }));
}
```